# Why can't I include Twitter in my project via NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

There is code of my component

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchContainer from './containers/searchContainer';
import TwitterContainer from './containers/twitterContainer';
import Twitter from 'twitter';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <SearchContainer />
              <TwitterContainer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

but after building i have [an error](http://pastebin.com/Luse5mPZ)

How solve this error?

[package.json](http://pastebin.com/4jMS3k2V)

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Show your `package.json`. Or report a bug to Twitter.

Comment: on each file npm show:
-- You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: Make sure that your version of the package is up to date, there aren't any errors in the github `package.json`, if that doesn't work, re-download the package manually from github and type `npm install` inside the folder

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with webpack and you need a loader for such thing. Once I had a problem with this same error message and it was because I missed the json-loader.